# ignore non existing method

Tags: php, class, methods, singleton

so let's say you have a singleton pattern or whatever:

```
class Smth{  
  public static function Foo(){
    static $instance;
    if(!condition()) return false; // <-- it's nothing...

    if(!($instance instanceof FooClass)) $instance = new FooClass();
    return $instance; // <-- it's a object and has that method
  }
}
```

so if I call `Smth::foo()->A_foo_method()` when `condition()` is met, then the method is executed and everything is OK.

But if `condition()` is not met, obviously I get a fatal error telling me that `Smth::foo()` is not a object etc...

How can I simply ignore the 2nd case.? I mean don't do anything, and don't show the fatal error.

(besides checking the condition() outside the class, when calling the method)

Comment: I assume you want `$instance` to be a reference to `Foo`? Could you also elaborate on `condition()`

Comment: `condition()` is a normal function that checks if the current page being displayed is a certain page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You do not want to do that.** This is a silent failure and it's not a good thing. When you call a method, you expect it to do something (especially a `getInstance`-like method in the Singleton pattern, which should return an instance). So yes, you have to check if `foo()` returns an actual object before calling `A_foo_method()`. Silently failing instead could create a debugging mess.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Special Case](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html) pattern.

Comment: Ugh, using Special Case *and* Singleton at the same time? That ought to boost sales on headache medication.

Comment: @netcoder Yeah probably ;) But I think it's a good fit for this special case of a question ;D

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are returning `false` from `Smth::foo()`. This should return the instance of `Foo` so the rest of the *chain* can run.

I assume you're doing lazy loading of `Foo`. Take a look at the following simple example of doing the same with a DB object and see if it scales.

```
private static $dbh;

public static function DBC() {
    if (self::$dbh === null) {
        self::$dbh = new mysqli($mysql['host'], $mysql['un'], $mysql['pw'], $mysql['db']);
    }

    return self::$dbh;
}
```